# Zoom levels in kml files on google maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

When I add GMarkers to a google map I can specifiy the min and max zoom levels at which the marker should be displayed using MarkerManager. Is there a way to specifiy this for Placemarks in kml files when they're displayed in Google Maps?

It looks like the region tag in kml does this, but only in Google Earth, not in Google Maps.

Comment: What are you using to parse the kml file and get the data into MarkerManager?

Comment: I was just adding the overlay with GGeoXml. I think that it may be possible with the EGeoXml library, but I haven't played with that yet.

Comment: That conflicts with another link I found off that page. According to this: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps The elements are supported. I am having the same problem with regions not working but according to the link above, they should work. Anyone have a solution? -Jason

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps only supports a limited subset of KML:
[Google Maps KML support](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html)