# OpenLayers support for Level of Details in KML

Tags: performance, openlayers, kml, region, level-of-detail

Does OpenLayers support toggling visibility of regions based on [Level of Details](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/regions#pixelrange) tag (`<Lod/>`)? As far as I researched and tried, none of the example KML from the reference mentioned works on OpenLayers/Google Maps. You may also be interested in [similar question regarding LoD in gmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582245/does-google-maps-support-kml-regions/18667860#18667860), which suggests that *nobody cares* about level of details support, thus the questions:

- Has anyone found *any* living proof that level of details actually have ever been working?
- If not, has anybody any clue how to make use of KML regions, if they will still be loaded to the browser all at once?
- If still not - do you know any way to solve the problem of loading plenty of features (>100000) in a smart and efficient way using KML? Or maybe the "officially supported" solution should be dropped for some custom implementation like zoom in/out events handling and manually toggling features' visibility?

Comment: i'm guessing your best solution for visualizing such a large number of features is to create map tiles from your data (and UTFGrids for interactivity if that's desired)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Layers does not support level of detail in KML. As you will have noticed, performance is horrific above a certain number of features -- this is not a failure of OpenLayers, but of existing browser rendering and DOM traversal issues. The advent of webGL will no doubt improve this greatly.

OpenLayers has something called a cluster strategy to get round this issue, whereby points are clustered together as you zoom out, based on various parameters you set: see http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html making the rendering much faster.

If you have more control over where the data is coming from, you could make different layers server side and load them as separate vector layers in OpenLayers, but with different maxResolution levels to control whether they are drawn or not.

As sfletche has suggested, you could also pre-render the kml into tiles at different zoom levels or create a wms, so that the work is done server side and you just end up with a raster. This approach will not help you much if you actually need to query those features client side.

Without knowing a bit more about you set up and usage requirements, it is hard to make firm recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.Regarding setup and usage requirements - use case is, that the items are interactive and their appearance may change after clicking/hovering. Also, the map key of the map should be interactive - layers' order may be altered.

Comment: I'll need to take a look at server-side layer rendering with UTFGrid for client-side events handling, maybe this is a good direction. Maybe also the clustering can be used to hide particular features (grouping them doesn't make sense in our use case).

Comment: And finally, as far as the browser performance is concerned - not only rendering time is a bottle-neck, but also the layer data download time. So better renderer strategy will only partially solve the issue - I guess that OpenLayers still loads ALL regions to the DOM recursively via NetworkLinks regardless of their level of detail or LonLatAltBox - which may kill the user experience, as there are multiple such layers with thousands of features. Same happens to the data clustered. **So it seems, that there is no such thing as an ultimately good solution**.

Comment: @zdanowiczkonrad Yes, this is certainly a problem area still with web mapping -- interacting with large numbers of polygon/line features. Another option you could try, if you don't mind loading the data into a spatial db like Postgres/Postgis, is to use a line generalization function to simplify the features at a certain zoom level and then reload greater levels of detail as people zoom in using web workers or some of the built in OL functionality. It will be interesting to see how webGL in OpenLayers3 improves vector rendering.